# Нужно ли ставить тире перед местоимением?

Tags: пунктуация, местоимение

Бренд DKNY – это отражение стиля современной женщины. Она - творческая личность, которая никогда не знает, куда же ее занесет новый день и поэтому всегда во всеоружии.

Подскажите, нужно ли после местоимения "она" ставить тире?

Answer (score 1):

Тире после местоимения "она" авторское, факультативное. При постановке тире **логическое  ударение делается на подлежащем,** которое становится центром высказывания, что, скорее всего,  не противоречит замыслу автора.

При отсутствии тире логически выделяется сказуемое, но в силу своей распространенности оно в меньшей степени нуждается в таком выделении.